# Get 2 documents in 1 MongoDB call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using MongoDB and Mongoose to retrieve documents from the database.

I have two IDs and I want to get the corresponding documents. I use

```
Collection.findById(id1).then(doc1 => {
  if (doc1) {
    Collection.findById(id2).then(doc2 => {
      if (doc2) {
```

Is it possible to do this in a single call?

I am wondering if it can be done with

```
{doc1, doc2} = Collection.find({ _id: $in: [id1, id2] });
```

and if this is better than my original approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoDB [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator to retrieve multiple documents, the syntax is

```
db.inventory.find( { id: { $in: [ 5, 15 ] } } )
```